# The argument type 'Future<List<User>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<void> Function()' in onRefresh when using RefreshIndicator

Tags: flutter, dart, pull-to-refresh, flutter-futurebuilder

I am having a **Future** that is fetching and populating users below

```
Future<List<User>> _fetchUsersListUsingLoop() async {
    try {
      
      var response = await http.get(
          Uri.parse(
              "https://api.json-generator.com/templates/Eh5AlPjYVv6C/data"),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer tltsp6dmnbif01jy9xfo9ssn4620u89xhuwcm5t3",
          });


      List<User> usersList = [];

      for (var u in json.decode(response.body)) {
        User user = User(u["email"], u["about"], u["name"], u["picture"],
            u["index"], u["imageFetchType"]);

        usersList.add(user);
      }

      return usersList;
    } catch (e) {
      log("FetchUsersListUsingLoopException $e");

      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

And below is how i am using `future` in **FutureBuilder** to call `_fetchUsersListUsingLoop()` and then use **ListView.builder** inside **RefreshIndicator** to show users in the `list`

```
body: SizedBox(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _fetchUsersListUsingLoop(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot asyncSnapshot) {
              if (asyncSnapshot.data == null) {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else {
                return RefreshIndicator(
                  // background color
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    // refresh circular progress indicator color
                    color: Colors.green,
                    onRefresh: _fetchUsersListUsingLoop(),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: asyncSnapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage:
                                NetworkImage(asyncSnapshot.data[index].picture),
                          ),
                          title: Text(asyncSnapshot.data[index].name),
                          subtitle: Text(
                              "${asyncSnapshot.data[index].email} \nUsing NetworkImage with backgroundImage"),
                        );
                      },
                    ));
              }
            }),
      ),
```

I am getting `The argument type 'Future<List<User>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<void> Function()'.` error in this line `onRefresh: _fetchUsersListUsingLoop(),` How can i be able to call `_fetchUsersListUsingLoop()` again when i swipe down to refresh

Comment: you should return usersList from _fetchUsersListUsingLoop() this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `_fetchUsersListUsingLoop` you should use `setState` to cause a rebuild so that `FutureBuilder` fetches the data again.

```
onRefresh: () => setState(() {})
```

That being said it's best to store your future in `initState` and update this future when needed by calling `setState`. This is from [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html):

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

```
Future<List<User>>? _usersFuture;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _usersFuture = _fetchUsersListUsingLoop();
}
```

Then:

```
onRefresh: () {
    setState(() {
      _usersFuture = _fetchUsersListUsingLoop();
    });
  }
```

Comment: i am getting the following error Undefined name '_usersFuture'

Comment: @EmmanuelNjorodongo Define it like this: `Future<List<User>>? _usersFuture;` Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this

```
onRefresh: _fetchUsersListUsingLoop(),
```

You are telling dart to call `_fetchUsersListUsingLoop` and expect it to return a function, then to call said function, what you want to do instead is tell it to just call `_fetchUsersListUsingLoop`:

```
onRefresh: _fetchUserListUsingLoop,
```

or ìf that doesn't work:

```
onRefresh: () async => _fetchUserListUsingLoop(),
```

But the problem is that **this will not actually work**, why? Because the future builder is already completed and nothing will change that, to fix your issue; you can reassign the future like this:

You need to declare a future:

```
late Future<List<User>> _user;
```

```
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _users,
            builder: (context, asyncSnapshot) {
              ...
                    onRefresh: _updateUsersFuture,
              ...
```

Then somewhere in your class you do:

```
Future<void> _updateUsersFuture() async {
  final newUsers = await _fetchUserListUsingLoop();
  setState(() => _users = newUsers);
}
```

and on initstate:

```
@override
void initState() {
  _users = _fetchUsersListUsingLoop();
  super.initState();
}
```